# Change object value on two components at same time?

Tags: angular

I read somewhere that is possible if i have object for example:

```
test{
test:'aaa'
}
```

And if i have two components :

`<component1></component1>` and `<component2></component2>`

And if i have

```
@Input() input;
```

So if i have something like this:

and if i change value in this input on component2 for object that will change on both component without service and emit. Is that possible and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a structure like:

```
<parent>
  <child1 [input]="hero"></child1>
  <child2 [input]="hero"></child2>
</parent>
```

Changing the hero property in the parent will change both children, but changing hero in `child1` will not change it in `child2` (without an emitter as you said). You would probably be better creating a service to hold the property and inject it into both child components through their constructors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the change within a nested component propagate you would need the use of `@Output` and `EventEmitter` within the nested component in order for it to work. In order the for a change in a nested component to effect another nested component within the same parent, the parent needs to be informed of the change. Angular isn't really setup to do it any other way without the use of services.

**Child Component**

```
@Input() input;
@Output() inputChanged = new EventEmitter<any>

someFunction() {
    this.inputChanged.emit('changed');
}
```

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<parentComponent>
    <childComponent1 [inputProperty]="input" (inputChanged)="parentFunction($event)"></childComponent1>
    <childComponent2 [inputProperty]="input" (inputChanged)="parentFunction($event)"></childComponent2>
</parentComponent>
```

The [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) makes it pretty clear.

The other way to do this is to create a singleton service that is globally available to entire application, or just the module your components reside in. You can do this using `Subject`, or `BehaviorSubject`.